Cumulative Sum of Monthly Balance (two tables)
I have two tables in power query, one has a list orders with bonus calculation for each orders (bonus is calculated in Power Query), and the second table has list of monthly payments to each sales person. Monthly payment is generally a sum of bonuses taken for a certain date. Is it added to the table manually every month for every person.
The list of orders is subject to constant corrections, so the amount of bonus may change a little after it has been paid and the balance must be included into the following month.

The table with orders has in fact many columns that influence the bonus calculation. I haven't included them into the example.
In order to use bonus and fact together in measures, I've merged the tables based on names and months, so every row of the table Orders now has the amount of payment of the respective month.

My skills in Power BI are basic. I have made visualization as a matrix with name, monthly bonus, monthly payment and balance for each month calculated as:
Total monthly bonus = SUM('Orders'[bonus])
Balance = 'Orders'[Total monthly bonus] - MIN('Orders'[bonus paid])
But what I need is the cumulative balance (in order to find out how much we should pay this month considering past corrections).

It took me some days to manage cumulative totals of bonuses and payments filtered by names and months, but they belong to different tables and I can't deduct one from another.
What I actually need is to calculate what will the bonus be this month for each name considering past corrections.
Any ideas and recommendations on general approach how to calculate it will be appreciated.

you can try this
group by the order table

then merge two tables

then create a column
balance =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        Orders,
        Orders[name] = EARLIER ( Orders[name] )
            && Orders[year - month] <= EARLIER ( Orders[year - month] )
    ),
    Orders[bonus]
)
    - SUMX (
        FILTER (
            Orders,
            Orders[name] = EARLIER ( Orders[name] )
                && Orders[year - month] <= EARLIER ( Orders[year - month] )
        ),
        Orders[bonus paid]
    )



Oh my God, it looks so simple, thanks a lot!

you are welcome. pls accept my answer as the solution if it works for you

May be interesting to mention that the visual table based on this new grouped by table, though created as linked with the original table, was not sensitive to page filters. So I still had to create the dimensional table with names (as recommended in the following  reply) and make a proper structure

Using the Star Schema approach, the Orders and Bonus paid tables are your Fact tables. You should add two more tables for Date and for Seller, these will be your Dimension tables. (It is common for folks to prefix Dim for Dimension tables, and Fact for Fact tables.)
Let's create your two Dimension tables.

Create the DimSeller table in Power Query:
In Power Query, right-click on Orders query and select Reference.
Rename this new query to DimSeller. Remove all columns except for name and then remove duplicates:

let
    Source = Orders,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"name"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"


Create the DimDate table in DAX.
Come out of Power Query, and in the main Power BI Desktop window, select New table under Modeling tab. Use the following DAX expression:

DimDate = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "year-month", EOMONTH([Date], -1) + 1
  )

You should now have your two Fact tables, and two Dimension tables. Next, you need to create relationships between these tables:

Drag the name column from Orders table to the DimSeller name column.
And the name column from Bonus paid table to the DimSeller name column.
Drag the date column from Orders to the DimDate Date column.
And the year-month column from Bonus paid table to the DimDate Date column.

Your model should look like:

And the relationships created are:

That's your model set-up now as a Star Schema.
Next, you will need to create a few Measures.
Order Bonus = SUM(Orders[bonus])

Paid Bonus = SUM('Bonus paid'[bonus paid])

Balance Bonus = 
  var thisMonth = MAX(DimDate[year-month])
  var cumBonusOrder = CALCULATE([Order Bonus], DimDate[year-month] <= thisMonth, REMOVEFILTERS(DimDate))
  var cumBonusPaid = CALCULATE([Paid Bonus], DimDate[year-month] <= thisMonth, REMOVEFILTERS(DimDate))
  var result = cumBonusOrder - cumBonusPaid
  return IF(NOT ISBLANK([Order Bonus]) || NOT ISBLANK([Paid Bonus]), result)

Lastly, create your visuals. With Star Schema, we use Dimension table columns and Measures (we shouldn't use columns from Fact tables). As an example:

